# Rails - Display Nested Attributes in an "Update" Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I am having a bit of difficulty getting my "update form" to display the nested attributes.  Specifically, images (e.g., "choices") to display.  All other data fields are showing.  Just not this is my form:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @template, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @template.id } do |f| %>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Update Your Template</legend>
  <%= f.text_field :prompt, :class => :span6, :placeholder => "Which one is running?", :autocomplete => :off %>
  <%= f.select 'group_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@groups, 'id', 'name', selected: @template.group.id) %>
   <div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
      <%= f.fields_for :template_assignments do |builder| %>
       <li class="span3" id="">
         <div class="thumbnail">
           <%= builder.text_field :choice_id %>
           <%= image_tag @template.template_assignments.builder.choice.image %>
         </div>
        </li>
      <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

The main line I am having trouble with is:

`<%= image_tag @template.template_assignments.builder.choice.image %>`

I cannot get it to iterate through each of the 4 nested attributes for the image.  It iterates through the 4 nested attributes pertaining to :choice_id, which displays correctly in the text_field.

If i change it to:

`<%= image_tag @template.template_assignments.first.choice.image %>`, it displays the first image no problem.

However, I need it to iterate and display the "first", "second", "third", and "fourth" images.

Any help on how to display these images, just as the image_id's are being displayed?

**EDIT:**
Here are my models

```
# app/models/template.rb

class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :group
 has_many :template_assignments, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :choices, :through => :template_assignments
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :template_assignments, allow_destroy: true
end
```

```
# app/models/template_assignment.rb

class TemplateAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :template
 belongs_to :choice
end
```

```
# app/models/choice.rb

 class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :template_assignments
  has_many :templates, :through => :template_assignments
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to just use `builder` directly, just like you're doing in the `text_field`.

```
<%= image_tag builder.choice.image %>
```

[UPDATE] after some trial and error the correct form would be :

```
<%= image_tag builder.object.choice.image %>
```

What's happening is that when `f.fields_for :template_assignments do |builder|` is used to render the nested items, the `builder` object that is `yield`ed to the block is not the object itself (in this case a `TemplateAssignment`), but is a `FormBuilder` object, which is what supplies the convenience methods like `builder.text_field`.  (If you tried to do `template_assignment.text_field` you'd get an error.)  The `builder` stores the object that it is representing in the form as `object`, so you can get a hold of your `template_assignment` object by using `builder.object`.  From there you can deal the the `template_assignment` like normal.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  But this is not working.  I don't know if this is because the "choice.image" is in it's own table, altogether. I've updated the OP to show my models.

Comment: To be more specific, when I use your suggestion, I get the following error: `"NoMethodError: undefined method `choice'"`

Comment: Maybe try `<%= image_tag builder.object.choice.image %>`?

Comment: That worked perfect!  Thank you.  For educational purposes, can you explain why `builder.object` would be needed?

Comment: No problem.  See the [UPDATE] that I added above.